# Datatable Counter Row At The End

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a normal datatable that outputs information and a few columns have numbers in them. Is it possible at the bottom of each column to do a tally on the total count in that column?

```
@foreach($res as $r)
          <tr>
              <td>
                {{-- {{ $user->fname }}   {{ $user->lname }} --}}
              {{ $r['name'] ?? null }}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{ $r[$threelastYearTitle] ?? 0 }}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{ $r[$twolastYearTitle] ?? 0 }}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{ $r[$onelastYearTitle] ?? 0 }}
              </td>
              <td>
                  {{ $r['booked']['onelastYearTitle']}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{ $r[$currentYearTitle] ?? 0 }}
              </td>
              <td>
                  {{ $r['booked']['currentYear']}}
              </td>
             <td>
               <a class="btn btn-default" href="/admin/user/{{ $id }}/edit">Edit</a>
              </td>
          </tr>
      @endforeach
</table>

$('#myTable').DataTable({
    "order": [],
    // "scrollX": true,
    "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets"  : 'no-sort',
      "orderable": false,
      "language": {
        "search": "Filter records:"
      }
  }],
  "pageLength": 25
});
```

Comment: yes but you will have to provide your table html or a subset of it

Comment: @BelowtheRadar updated code

Comment: Ok thank you. What is that DataTable library you are using? Can you post a link to its repositary?

Comment: https://datatables.net

Comment: There's a good example for this on the DataTables website: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

Comment: These links can also help in addition to the one above 
 https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()  https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/37830/how-to-add-row-in-the-footer-that-sum-each-column

Comment: @OPMat I just made my own sum algorithm and now you show me the easy route lol. Thanks though!

Comment: Ha, doing it the hard way is always a good learning exercise :)

Comment: Please avoid link only answers. We really dont know if the link exists in 14 days ...I believe this answer should have been posted as a  comment only.

Comment: @davidkonrad - that's a fair point on the link, I tend to avoid repeating info as that also goes stale, but happy to post examples too.

Comment: @colin0117, please dont take it personal :) If you just have copy pasted the code with your own comments there had been no problem.  You can do it now! I know your concerns, you are a fair person with high moral, but even those with the highest rep on this forum have copy pasted code from somewhere else.  The only really bad thing to do in this regard is to copy and paste another answer from SO. If you can find an existing question+answer, mark the question as duplicate. This is not the case here. In my opinion, you are free to copy paste what ever from the link and get the reps out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Example to sum the column 3 (index start with 0)

```
fnFooterCallback : function(nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++) {
        total += parseFloat(aaData[aiDisplay[i]][2]);
    }
    var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
    nCells[2].innerHTML = "Total " + total;
}
```